# C++ code: not understood

Tags: c++

Ok, so I have C++ code, where the program needs to check if the entered number is a palindrome.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int n, num, digit, rev = 0;

     cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
     cin >> num;

     n = num;

     do
     {
         digit = num % 10;
         rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
         num = num / 10;
     } while (num != 0);

     if (n == rev)
         cout << " The number is a palindrome";
     else
         cout << " The number is not a palindrome";

    return 0;
}
```

but I have a problem. I do not understand this part:

```
 do
 {
     digit = num % 10;
     rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
     num = num / 10;
 }
```

Can someone explain what is happening in these lines?

I do not understand how the program calculated whether it is a palindrome or not.

Comment: _"someone would explain what is happening in these activities?"_ A bit of math.

Comment: This just constructs a reverse of `num` in `rev`.

Comment: What part of that code do you not understand?  Do you know what the operators are and how they work?  If so you can do the steps on pencil and paper to see how they work or step through the code with your debugger and watch what happens.

Comment: @NathanOliver I try with pencil and paper, but stil not understand, how this part construct reverse of `num`..... if I enter number 12321, then after this `digit = num % 10;` digit will be 1, right? or it will be 1232?

Comment: what IDE software do you use to program? Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it calculates a number which is calculating by reversing each digit of the original number, if, in the end, both numbers are equal then number is palindrome.

You should try to test the code for a specific input, or add some print statements.

Start with `num = 234`

```
// iteration 1
digit = num % 10 = 234 % 10 = 4; // remainder of division
rev = (0 * 10) + 4 = 4;
num = num / 10 = 23; // integer division is truncated
// iteration 2
digit = num % 10 = 23 % 10 = 3;
rev = (4 * 10) + 3 = 43;
num = num / 10 = 2;
// iteration 3
digit = num % 10 = 2 % 10 = 2;
rev = (43 * 10) + 2 = 432; // you can see that 432 is the reverse of 234 in literal sense
num = num / 10 = 0;
```

so `432 != 234`, hence it's not palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically inverting the number, `1234` becomes `4321` for instance. It does it digit by digit by performing arithmetic operations with base `10`.

`num % 10` returns the remainder of the division by `10`. Basically we are reading the least significant decimal digit from the number `num`. Later on `num` is divided by `10` so that we strip it from it's last digit to continue the iteration.

So in `1234` for instance, the operation returns `4` and saves it in the variable `digit`, and then `1234` suffers and integer division by 10 to become `123` so that the next iteration we collect `3`. (Integer divisions are not rounded.) The process repeats until this number becomes `0` and the loops stop as it's condition is `while (num != 0)`.

Each iteration will accumulate `digit` to the variable `rev`, this time multiplying `rev` by `10` each iteration so that we build the reverse number.

`rev` starts as `0`, that multiplied by 10 is still `0`, plus `4` becomes `4`. Next iteration it starts as `4`, multiplied by `10` becomes `40`, plus `3` becomes `43`, and so on until we have `4321`.

At this point `num` is `0` and the loop stops. The computer can can now directly test if `4321` equal `1234` to determine if it's a palindrome number.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately obvious. Essentially the idea is to "pop" numbers off the end of the user input number and "push" them on to the reversed number *one digit at a time*.

It may help you to see a slightly refactored version with comments:

```
int input = 0;          // The user input. Does not change after it's been entered.
int reversed = 0;       // The reversed user input, gradually built one number at a time.

int working_value = 0;  // Starts off as the user input and numbers are 
                        // gradually removed from the end


// Get the user input           
cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
cin >> input;

working_value = input;

do
{
    //Get the last digit of the working value
    int last_digit = working_value % 10;
    //Remove the last digit from the working value
    working_value = working_value / 10;

    // "Shift" the reversed digits, and add the last digit of the
    // working value
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + last_digit;

} while (working_value != 0);

// ... identical from here
```

---

It may also be useful to go through a full example. We'll use the value **517**.

The user inputs the number and our working value is set to 517.

```
user_input    = 517
working_value = 517
reversed      = 0
```

On our first iteration in the loop, we get the last digit of the working value and remove it.

```
user_input    = 517
working_value = 51
last_digit    = 7
```

We then perform our shift on our current reversed value and add the last digit. `(0 * 10) + 7 = 7`

```
reversed      = 7
```

Our working value is not zero so we go around the loop again and get the last digit of the working value and remove it:

```
user_input    = 517
working_value = 5
last_digit    = 1
```

We then perform our shift on our current reversed value and add that last digit. `(7 * 10) + 1 = 71`

```
reversed      = 71
```

Our working value is not zero so we go around the loop again and get the last digit of the working value and remove it. There was only one digit so working_value becomes zero.

```
user_input    = 517
working_value = 0
last_digit    = 5
```

We then perform our shift on our current reversed value and add the last digit. `(71 * 10) + 5 = 715`

```
reversed      = 715
```

Now our working value **is zero** so we stop. We have built the number 715 as the reverse of 517. We can now simply compare the numbers and see that they are not the same.